# Where the hell am I?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I'm playing **Technic** single player, v7.0.1. I've not played it very much, hence my confusion... what is all this?

[[image]

<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6sWX.jpg)

As you can see, I'm at **level 2** - ie, bedrock level. However, I stumbled across a grass floor and a *lot* of interconnected corridors rather than the usual vanilla Minecraft experience. There is a *ton* of ore here of various kinds:

- Diamond
- Redstone
- Silver
- Nikolite
- Tin
- Uranium
- Iron
- .. the list goes on.

There are also some mobs spawning. This *may* be because I've placed torches and there's grass, which are requirements for many mobs to spawn. I've encountered

- Chickens
- Sheep
- Scorpions
- Ghosts

There's strange 1 block-deep pools of water and a lot of small lava flows. Underneath th grass and water pools is bedrock.

I'm loving this place, but sadly - I got lost. Whilst I'm running around voraciously mining and trying to find my way home, I'd like to know where I am! So **the question** is: What is this place and what mod generated it? Is this a common area, or a rare find?

Comment: Could you tell me what texturepack you are using it looks amazing

Comment: SummerFields - http://www.planetminecraft.com/texture_pack/summerfields-v15-for-181-196-ready/

Comment: You aren't on vanilla Minecraft, though. Your using mods that add new ores to the game, you have MAtmos, and the compass. Are you using Tekkit or Technic Pack? This is either a feature or a glitch in a mod you have. So, (unless your on a snapshot and this is a hidden feature), this isn't part of vanilla Minecraft (or at least, not documented).

Comment: Wait, what are you asking? What that place is and why it is (valid question in my opinion)...or where you are and how to get home (CLOSE IT NOW!)...so?

Comment: I'm going to say this is a rare find. It is probably an error in the code, most likely the mod. I would suggest talking this over in the Minecraft Forums where you got the mod.

Comment: But that is pretty darn awesome! And kinda creepy...

Comment: This could be the work of better dungeons, but I'm pretty sure this is probably a glitch. I would recommend posting on the [technic forums](http://forums.technicpack.net/), to see if any of the mods know what this is. Also is there bedrock bellow the grass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First time I've ever answered my own question!!

I posted on the Technic board, and it turns out that it *is* in-fact part of Better Dungeons as Dimtuhop suggested. These are apparently rare, but intended, cave systems.

[Thread on Technic Forum.](http://forums.technicpack.net/threads/bug-or-feature.13417/)

So, for those interested, it's worth searching for! Just dig down to bedrock level and tunnel around. It's actually quite fun to explore and (although it appears to have the same amount of ore) there's lots of ore!